# SVG <title> text loop gets the last element of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I added a `<title>`tag under the `<g>`tag of my svg file. Now I need to put some text in the `<title>` tag to make a mousehover tooltip later. The text I will put in `<title>` comes from a `name`attribute of the second `g` tag. I am making a loop, but it always write the last element of the array into the `<title>`. Following is the basic structure of the svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="product123">
    <g id="id1" name="1AC1">
        <path style="stroke:black; fill:none;" d="/some path"/>
        <title>//text comes from name attr of "g"</title> //tags added with the code below
    </g>
    <g id="id2" name="1AC2">
        <path style="stroke:black; fill:none;" d="/some path"/>
        <title>//text comes from name attr of "g"</title>
    </g>
    <g id="id3" name="1AC3">
        <path style="stroke:black; fill:none;" d="/some path"/>
        <title>//text comes from name attr of "g"</title>
    </g>
    .........
```

Here is the JS code to get in SVG elements and create the `<title>` tag and pass the `name` attr of `<g>`

```
var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
$('g>g').each(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    var c = function () {
        return $input.attr("name") //get the "name" attributes and store in var c
    };
    $(this).append("<title/>"); //create <title> tag
    $('g>g>title').each(function() { //I am in <title> tag
       $(this).text(c) //pass all "c" as text to each <title>
       });
    });
});
```

now with the code above, I am able to put `<title>`tags but the returned text is the same for each`<title>`. And the value is always `1AC3` which is the `name` attr of `g id="id3"`. I think it is about the callback of `.each()`. But I couldn't solve.. How can I put each `name` attr of `<g>`as the text value of `<title>`? Thanks.

**Edit PS.** The svg file is exported from another platform and source code of exporter is not available to define the `<title>` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're looping through the `g>g`'s twice and over-writing the original value on the second run through.

```
var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
$('g>g').each(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    var c = function () {
        return $input.attr("name") //get the "name" attributes and store in var c
    };


    /*
    $(this).append("<title/>"); //create <title> tag

    // This part here is over-writing your previous title.
    $('g>g>title').each(function() { //I am in <title> tag
       $(this).text(c) //pass all "c" as text to each <title>
       });
    });
    */

    // Use this instead to set the title on the current
    // element. 
    $(this).attr("title", c); // correct way to set the title attribute
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I tried this method before, but it wrote the "name" in <g> tags. Following is one of the <g> tag based on your suggestion
`<g id="id4" name="1AC5">1AC5</g>`

Comment: see my updated answer. The correct way to set the title attribute is `$(this).attr("title", c)`.

Comment: Thanks. updated answer put another attribute in the <g> tag now, both "name" and "title" attributes has the same value. I think keeping them inside <g> tag does not allow it show as tooltip with svg files. But thanks for your help. please let me know for any suggestions.

Comment: Did my answer answer your question: "SVG <title> text loop gets the last element of array"? If it did, then please accept it. The "tooltip" question is another issue so best to post a separate question for that.